# Install tn5250 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, apt, wine, network-manager, vpn

I want to apologize for the length that this is going to be.  I am going to be as specific as I can and have as much detail in it that I can think of.  I am doing my best to get away from Windows and run strictly Linux.  I have loaded Ubuntu 16.04 on a spare laptop that has been laying around for quite some time now. The system specifications of the laptop are as follows:

Memory - 3.8 GiB
Processor - Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz x 2
Graphics - Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset
OS Type - x64
Disk - 153.2 GB

I'm trying to install tn5250 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I got the package from a link that someone on here directed me to.  tn5250 is the only program that I can use through the VPN for my work.  I figured out how to connect to the VPN using openconnect.  When I tried to install tn5250, the `./configure --prefix=/opt --with-ssl` ran like a charm.  The `make` command, on-the-other-hand, ran into an error.  I'm trying to use Linux exclusively.  I refuse to put Windows OS on any of my computers, and would like it if I didn't have to put it on a virtual machine like \VirtualBox.  Is there anyone out there that can help me with this?

I posted the terminal output of the `make` command using the script command in terminal, then copying it from vim amd pasting it in here. 
Below is the terminal output for installing tn5250.  `./configure --prefix=/op --with-ss` runs through without any errors.  I run into problems on the `make` command.

```
dustin@dustin-laptop:~/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4$ make  
make  all-recursive  
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4'  
Making all in lib5250  
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lib5250'  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/buffer.Tpo" -c -o buffer.lo buffer.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/buffer.Tpo" ".deps/buffer.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/buffer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
mkdir .libs  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c buffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/buffer.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c buffer.c -o buffer.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/conf.Tpo" -c -o conf.lo conf.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/conf.Tpo" ".deps/conf.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/conf.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/conf.Tpo -c conf.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/conf.o conf.c: In function 'tn5250_config_load':  
conf.c:258:5: **warning:** ignoring return value of **'fgets'**, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
     fgets (buf, sizeof (buf) - 1, f);  
     ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/conf.Tpo -c conf.c -o conf.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo" -c -o dbuffer.lo dbuffer.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo" ".deps/dbuffer.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dbuffer.Tpo -c dbuffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/dbuffer.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dbuffer.Tpo -c dbuffer.c -o dbuffer.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/debug.Tpo" -c -o debug.lo debug.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/debug.Tpo" ".deps/debug.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/debug.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/debug.Tpo -c debug.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/debug.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/debug.Tpo -c debug.c -o debug.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/display.Tpo" -c -o display.lo display.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/display.Tpo" ".deps/display.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/display.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/display.Tpo -c display.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/display.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/display.Tpo -c display.c -o display.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/field.Tpo" -c -o field.lo field.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/field.Tpo" ".deps/field.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/field.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/field.Tpo -c field.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/field.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/field.Tpo -c field.c -o field.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/macro.Tpo" -c -o macro.lo macro.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/macro.Tpo" ".deps/macro.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/macro.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/macro.Tpo -c macro.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/macro.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/macro.Tpo -c macro.c -o macro.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/menu.Tpo" -c -o menu.lo menu.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/menu.Tpo" ".deps/menu.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/menu.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/menu.Tpo -c menu.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/menu.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/menu.Tpo -c menu.c -o menu.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/printsession.Tpo" -c -o printsession.lo printsession.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/printsession.Tpo" ".deps/printsession.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/printsession.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/printsession.Tpo -c printsession.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/printsession.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/printsession.Tpo -c printsession.c -o printsession.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/record.Tpo" -c -o record.lo record.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/record.Tpo" ".deps/record.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/record.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/record.Tpo -c record.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/record.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/record.Tpo -c record.c -o record.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo" -c -o scrollbar.lo scrollbar.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo" ".deps/scrollbar.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scrollbar.Tpo -c scrollbar.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/scrollbar.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scrollbar.Tpo -c scrollbar.c -o scrollbar.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scs.Tpo" -c -o scs.lo scs.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/scs.Tpo" ".deps/scs.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/scs.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scs.Tpo -c scs.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/scs.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scs.Tpo -c scs.c -o scs.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/session.Tpo" -c -o session.lo session.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/session.Tpo" ".deps/session.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/session.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/session.Tpo -c session.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/session.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/session.Tpo -c session.c -o session.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/sslstream.Tpo" -c -o sslstream.lo sslstream.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/sslstream.Tpo" ".deps/sslstream.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/sslstream.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sslstream.Tpo -c sslstream.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sslstream.o  
sslstream.c: In function **'ssl_getTelOpt'**:  
sslstream.c:179:14: **warning:** type of **'what'** defaults to **'int'** [-Wimplicit-int] static char 
*ssl_getTelOpt(what)  
 ^  
sslstream.c: In function **'ssl_log_SB_buf'**:  
sslstream.c:310:4: **warning:** format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]  
    fprintf(tn5250_logfile,ssl_getTelOpt(type=*buf++));  
    ^  
sslstream.c: In function **'tn5250_ssl_stream_init'**:  
sslstream.c:372:16: **warning:** implicit declaration of function **'SSLv2_client_method'** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
         meth = SSLv2_client_method();               
                ^  
sslstream.c:372:14: **warning:** assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  
         meth = SSLv2_client_method();           
              ^  
sslstream.c:375:14: **warning:** assignment discards **'const'** qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]  
         meth = SSLv3_client_method();           
              ^  
sslstream.c:378:14: **warning:** assignment discards **'const'** qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]  
         meth = SSLv23_client_method();           
              ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sslstream.Tpo -c sslstream.c -o sslstream.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/stream.Tpo" -c -o stream.lo stream.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/stream.Tpo" ".deps/stream.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/stream.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stream.Tpo -c stream.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/stream.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stream.Tpo -c stream.c -o stream.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo" -c -o telnetstr.lo telnetstr.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo" ".deps/telnetstr.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/telnetstr.Tpo -c telnetstr.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/telnetstr.o  
telnetstr.c: In function **'getTelOpt'**:  
telnetstr.c:161:14: **warning:** type of 'what' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]  
 static char *getTelOpt(what)  
              ^  
telnetstr.c: In function **'log_SB_buf'**:  
telnetstr.c:285:4: **warning:** format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]  
    fprintf(tn5250_logfile,getTelOpt(type=*buf++));  
    ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/telnetstr.Tpo -c telnetstr.c -o telnetstr.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/terminal.Tpo" -c -o terminal.lo terminal.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/terminal.Tpo" ".deps/terminal.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/terminal.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/terminal.Tpo -c terminal.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/terminal.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/terminal.Tpo -c terminal.c -o terminal.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/utility.Tpo" -c -o utility.lo utility.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/utility.Tpo" ".deps/utility.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/utility.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/utility.Tpo -c utility.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/utility.o  
utility.c: In function **'tn5250_daemon'**:  
utility.c:114:5: **warning:** implicit declaration of function 'umask' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
     umask(0);  
     ^  
utility.c: In function **'tn5250_log_open'**:  
utility.c:391:4: **warning:** implicit declaration of function **'fchmod'** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
    fchmod(fileno(tn5250_logfile), 0600);  
    ^  
utility.c: In function **'tn5250_daemon'**:  
utility.c:105:7: **warning:** ignoring return value of **'chdir'**, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
       chdir("/");  
       ^  
utility.c:111:9: **warning:** ignoring return value of **'dup'**, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
         dup(0); dup(0);  
         ^  
utility.c:111:17: **warning:** ignoring return value of **'dup'**, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
         dup(0); dup(0);  
                 ^  
utility.c: In function **'tn5250_run_cmd'**:  
utility.c:607:12: **warning:** ignoring return value of **'system'**, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
            system(cmd);  
            ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/utility.Tpo -c utility.c -o utility.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/version.Tpo" -c -o version.lo version.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/version.Tpo" ".deps/version.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/version.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c version.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/version.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c version.c -o version.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/window.Tpo" -c -o window.lo window.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/window.Tpo" ".deps/window.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/window.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c window.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/window.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c window.c -o window.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/wtd.Tpo" -c -o wtd.lo wtd.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/wtd.Tpo" ".deps/wtd.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/wtd.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/wtd.Tpo -c wtd.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/wtd.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/wtd.Tpo -c wtd.c -o wtd.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o lib5250.la -rpath /opt/lib  buffer.lo conf.lo dbuffer.lo debug.lo display.lo field.lo macro.lo menu.lo printsession.lo record.lo scrollbar.lo scs.lo session.lo sslstream.lo stream.lo telnetstr.lo terminal.lo utility.lo version.lo window.lo wtd.lo  -lssl -lcrypto   
gcc -shared  .libs/buffer.o .libs/conf.o .libs/dbuffer.o .libs/debug.o .libs/display.o .libs/field.o .libs/macro.o .libs/menu.o .libs/printsession.o .libs/record.o .libs/scrollbar.o .libs/scs.o .libs/session.o .libs/sslstream.o .libs/stream.o .libs/telnetstr.o .libs/terminal.o .libs/utility.o .libs/version.o .libs/window.o .libs/wtd.o  -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,-soname -Wl,lib5250.so.0 -o .libs/lib5250.so.0.0.0  
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.so.0 && ln -s lib5250.so.0.0.0 lib5250.so.0)  
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.so && ln -s lib5250.so.0.0.0 lib5250.so)  
ar cru .libs/lib5250.a  buffer.o conf.o dbuffer.o debug.o display.o field.o macro.o menu.o printsession.o record.o scrollbar.o scs.o session.o sslstream.o stream.o telnetstr.o terminal.o utility.o version.o window.o wtd.o  
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')  
ranlib .libs/lib5250.a  
creating lib5250.la  
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.la && ln -s ../lib5250.la lib5250.la)  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lib5250'  
Making all in lp5250d  
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lp5250d'  
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I../lib5250  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scs2ascii.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo" -c -o scs2ascii.o scs2ascii.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo" ".deps/scs2ascii.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
scs2ascii.c: In function **‘main’**:  
scs2ascii.c:70:3: **warning:** implicit declaration of function **‘scs_main’** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
   scs_main (scs);  
   ^  
scs2ascii.c: In function **‘scs2ascii_ff’**:  
scs2ascii.c:142:3: **warning:** implicit declaration of function **‘scs_ff’** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
   scs_ff (This);  
   ^  
scs2ascii.c: In function **‘scs2ascii_nl’**:  
scs2ascii.c:156:3: **warning:** implicit declaration of function **‘scs_nl’** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
   scs_nl (This);  
   ^  
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o scs2ascii  scs2ascii.o ../lib5250/lib5250.la -lssl -lcrypto 
mkdir .libs  
gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/scs2ascii scs2ascii.o  ../lib5250/.libs/lib5250.so -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/lib  
../lib5250/.libs/lib5250.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
Makefile:265: recipe for target 'scs2ascii' failed  
make[2]: *** [scs2ascii] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lp5250d'  
Makefile:335: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed  
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4'  
Makefile:226: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Not being versed in the tools you use, I can only suggest two ideas. First, see if you can find the "functions" of those tools are available in a GNU tool rather than trying to run the exact same tools in Wine. Second, and a bad fall-back in my opinion, is to see if a VM could solve the problem. Maybe have the VM act a proxy between your system and the VPNs. For tn5250 [see here](http://tn5250.sourceforge.net/). FileMaker, OTOH I don't see any alternatives to, globally, but I don't know what you use it for either, so there may, or may not, be alternative solutions.

Comment: I followed your link to get tn5250, but I am running into an error when running the " make " command. @GypsySpellweaver

Comment: My experience with using source packages is limited, but majority of the errors I get are because of incompatible version of linked libraries. My observation is that the Ask Ubuntu user-base is mostly users who want to use the desktop, and avoid the terminal. AKA ex-Win users who like the "It just works" approach. That's what Ubuntu is supposed to be, to that's what the users expect. That also means that help for this problem may not exist here. I'd suggest breaking the issue into smaller pieces and asking the questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) SE site.

Comment: Haha, that makes sense.  I will definitely check out that site.  Thank you for all of your help!!@GypsySpellweaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to install tn5250 on Ubuntu is to use binary packages rather than compile this yourself. tn5250 was previously packaged as part of Debian and Ubuntu, but it has been removed from current versions.

However, with Debian/Ubuntu, it is often possible to run packages from an older version in the current version. I successfully run tn5250 in current Debian (Jessie), using a Debian package from an earlier version.

(Note, my lack of reputation on this site is preventing me from posting more than two links, hence you will need to reconstitute some of the links here.)

To do this:

1. Download the latest tn5250 package for your architecture from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tn5250/
2. Install that with: `dpkg -i tn5250_xxxxxxx.deb`.  This step will probably fail due to unmet dependencies.
3. For each unmet dependency, repeat the process.  Look up the package under http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/, download the latest available that meets the dependency criteria and install it. For example, tn5250 might require libssl0.9.8; you would download that from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/
4. This is an iterative process, you may have to install dependencies of dependencies

Once that finishes, you should have a usable install of tn5250 on your system.

There is a risk that it won't be installable on your system due to dependency problems, one way of finding out is just to try it.

The above process is a manual version of what the apt tool does.  If you don't want to do that manually but prefer apt to handle it, you need to add the old version of Ubuntu to your apt sources:

1. Find out which was the latest version of Ubuntu that included tn5250.  You can do that by looking in the lists under http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, e.g. http //old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz for natty (Ubuntu from 2011) (and also look in precise, from 2012, under http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/) (The online tool I know of that searces ubuntu versions, http://packages.ubuntu.com/ will *not* search in obsolete versions. If anyone knows one that does, that would be helpful here.)
2. Add an apt source to your apt sources for that release (see instructions elsewhere).
3. Use apt to install tn5250 (e.g. `apt-get install tn5250`).  That will install tn5250 and all dependencies if possible in your version.

It would be useful to know if this works for you.

Alternatively, to successfully compile the package as you attempted to do would require you fixing the  "../lib5250/.libs/lib5250.so: undefined reference to SSLv2_client_method' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" error, but modifying code.  If you did so, it would be great to publish the updated tn5250 source code.  IIRC, SSLv2 is depreciated on modern Linux, I suspect that could be a big job.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I did this according to your help.  1. Downloaded tn5250_0.17.4-2_amd64.deb from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tn5250/  2. Ran command dpkg -i tn5250_0.17.4-2_amd64.deb  It did complain about dependencies, but only the libssl0.9.8 dependency.  3.  Downloaded the dependency from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download  4. Ran command dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb  After that it worked like a charm!  Can't figure out how to set macros in tn5250, but I have a macro keyboard so no biggie.  Thanks again!!